# Working with intervals and data

Tags: highcharts

I need do a chart with intervals (rangeSelector Buttons), so the idea that I have is, First of all, load the data by days to enable the rangeSelector Buttons.

Creating an event with setExtremes, I can tell when you click on a time interval and then here comes my question, it would be the correct method to add a new series to keep the information in the "Navigation" to be loaded before?

For example: http://www.coindesk.com/price/

When you click on the time intervals, the "Navigation" but does not change the "points" of the range

Comment: It works for me. The range in the main chart reflects the span requested (1 yr, 1wk, etc) as well as the windowing on the navigator series. What is your expected outcome?

Comment: For me, when you click on i.e 1m / 1y then range on navigator is limited as should be.

Comment: If I make a chart per days, with intervals each 30min per example, are many data, so as I can avoid and load only the required range but taking the data in the navigator, and enable the rangeSelector buttons

Comment: Ok, I put it back:
I have a chart with loaded data per example, ago 1 month, I load the chart with data per day each 30 minutes, and I fixed the current range with the min in "xAxis".

The rangeSelector buttons appears, but I have the next problem: I want see the interval of current day each 5 minutes, and when I select the button "1h" I need ¿load? the new data, I currently have 30 minute intervals, and I need to see every 5 min intervals during the intervening "1h"

Comment: I have the plan, I have to do a query for "normal" data without the last 1 hour ago by example and attach another query with the data 1 hour ago with 5 minute intervals :)

Comment: In case when you need to have "dynamic" tickPositions you need to use tickPositioner function and prepare your own function which will return ticks. http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner